# How to set up PrivateRoutes using react-router-dom with passport integration

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am currently trying to set up a Private route custom component that returns a normal route () if user is authenticated or gets redirected to the login page.

Here is my PrivateRoute component:

```
PrivateRoute.js
<imports>
...
</imports>
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (  
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
        sessionStorage.getItem('auth') ? (
        <Component {...props}/>
      ) : (
        <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/signin',
          state: { from: props.location }
        }}/>
      )
    )}/>
  )
export default PrivateRoute;
```

The code above works but I am getting issues with my sessionStorage. In my sessionStorage I store a boolean value that basically gets updated every time a user logs in and logs out. The boolean value is fetched from the server using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) promise function below:

```
authenticationCtrl.js

<imports>
...
</imports>

const authenticate =  async () => {
    let response = await axios.get('/test/login').then(res => sessionStorage.setItem('auth', res.data.isAuthenticated)) 
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
//sets the boolean that gets updated by server when user signs - in(up)/out).
return response;
}
```

I call the method above in my login and signup component.
The problem I am currently having is that whenever I log in or signup I still get redirected to the login page even when the sessionStorage.getItem('auth') has been updated. I have to go to my root page and then access my private route through there or write the route url onto my browser to gain access.

```
Signin.js

<imports>
...
</imports>

export default (props) => {
    const [detail, setDetail] = useState({
        username: "",
        pass: "",
        err: ""
      });

function handleChange(event) {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
    
        setDetail(prevValue => {
          return { ...prevValue, [name]: value, err: ''};
        });
      }

      function onSubmit(event){
          event.preventDefault();

          const {history} = props;

          login({
              username: detail.username,
              password: detail.pass
        }, (data) => {
            console.log(data);
            if(data.message){ //if authenticated
                history.push('/user/home');
            }else {
                setDetail(prevValue => {
                    return {...prevValue, err: 'Failed to login'}
                })
            }
          });
          authenticate(); //method from authenticationCtrl.js
      }
```

I need help with how to fix this?
I want to be able to login or signup and not be redirected back to those pages, but access my PrivateRoutes directly.

In the back-end I am using passport and express-sessions for security. I have added them as middleware and I use the req.isAuthenticated variable in the request to check whether the user has been authenticated and update the client side sessiosStorage.getItem('auth'), to access the PrivateRoutes.

```
Routes.js
<imports>
...
</imports>

router.route('/login')
.get((req,res) => {
  res.json({isAuthenticated: req.isAuthenticated()});
})

.post(user.login); //from routeController.js renamed as user on import.
```

```
routeController.js

exports.login = (req,res) => {
    const user = new User({
      username: req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password
  });
  
  req.login(user, (err) => {
      if(err){
          console.log(err);
          res.json({message: false});
      }else{
          passport.authenticate('local', {failureRedirect: '/test/login'})(req,res, () => {
              res.json({message: true});
          });
      }
  })
}
```

Thanks in Advance :>

Answer (score 0):

It was an import error. I accidentally imported an express module in my react application. I had to imports with the same name so automatic import thought it was the one associated with express.
Thanks to everyone for trying :>